# Alfresco workflow notification email not being sent

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

So we are running Alfresco Community 5.2, and using Alfresco Share primarily. I'm pretty sure that I set up the configs for outbound emails properly in the `alfresco-global.properties` file, since I can receive my test message and there are no errors in the logs.

But for some reason, upon creating a new workflow and assigning a user to it, the selected user does not receive a notification email, even when `Send Email Notifications` is checked.

What am I missing here?

Comment: is there any error after workflow creation in log?

Comment: I edited my log4j.properties file to show the logs when there is mail activity, and there are no errors

Comment: How did you check test message?

Comment: @Sanjay via the tail command on catalina.out. I also set some notifications in log4j.properties to `debug` mode to see any activity by the MailExecuter

Comment: Can you try this : try to add user to any site,it will sending email.

Comment: @Sanjay it seemed the problem was the security settings for our mail server. This is resolved already. Anyway, I have a new question, maybe you can help? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528492/alfresco-add-recipients-name-to-workflow-notification-email-template